# Как присваивается адресное пространство модулю в ring0

Tags: c++, windows, kernel

При запуске процесса, происходит обращение к ядру OS Windows, на добавление в адресное пространство памяти (от 0x00000000-0x7FFFFFFF) нужных модулей(не из KnownList) для работы процесса ?

Если это примерно так, то как называются функции которые за это отвечают и можно ли в них внедриться.

Мне не нужно открывать процесс чтобы узнать адрес, я хочу узнать как он формируется.

Comment: Вы бы хоть ОС указали...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Windows